# VPN with two mac users

Tags: macos, vpn

I have two users accounts on my computer, one needs to stay connected to a VPN while the other account, both being logged in, is not supposed to use the VPN. OS X 10.9 seems to only give me global VPN access or none. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You are talking about a single machine with a single network connection with a single MAC address, etc.. Using multiple accounts on the same machine does not change that but using Virtual Machines does... With Parallels you could setup a MacOS VM that connected via VPN, that would be better than Virtual Box... Or maybe there is a way to use the WiFi or a Thunderbolt to Ethernet dongle to use a separate network connection and VPN over just that... interesting.

Comment: Is the second user an adminstrator account or a standart unpreviledged one?

Comment: User 1 is administrator. User 2 can be either or. Currently it is an administrator account

Comment: You _might_ be able to do something about this by setting up different network ['locations'](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202480) for each one and then setting up a `launchd` User Agent to run `networksetup -switchtolocation $NAME_OF_LOCATION` at log-in (though I'm not sure yet what you might set up to run when it's time to log _off_ to switch your location _back_, and I _also_ haven't yet figured out how to stop VPN service settings from being global, either, so there's _that…_)

Answer (score 4):

I have a *very* dirty work around. So I hope someone will come up with a better solution.

What I did is setup a [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) virtual machine with some minimalistic Linux that can do VPN. Once the virtual machine is connected the user can use the VPN inside the machine (but other users not). Since I needed to use some apps in the host system I finally set up a proxy in the virtual machine that would forward my VPN users data.

As I said *dirty*...

**UPDATE 2022:**
As I see this answer still is popular - nowadays it is possible to achieve this through Docker as well. Try using [docker-vpn](https://github.com/ethack/docker-vpn).

Comment: Dirty indeed, I was considering a Raspberry PI solution, but am actually hoping for a 'proper' solution

Comment: You have my upvote. This might be dirty, but this is a legit solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible without virtual machines. Networks exist on a system level and not the user level. Even with per-app VPN, you’re constantly juggling and testing and losing control of things in practice.

It was not feasable in the past, but with Apple hypervisor, you can do lightweight ARM VM that scale well or choose a dedicated cluster of low cost Unix devices. They are now economical for this sort of scale out of apps and network customization you contemplate with two accounts on macOS.

- https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/
- https://raspberrytips.com/install-vmware-esxi-raspberry-pi/
- https://williamlam.com/2020/10/vsan-witness-using-raspberry-pi-4-esxi-arm-fling.html